# Where to set WPS portlet permissions

Tags: websphere-portal

I am deploying a portlet on WPS 6.1. When I try to access the portlet, I get :

```
We are sorry, but you have no permissions to see this page
```

Where do I set permission? I just created a page and added the portlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you go to the Manage Pages portlet, there's an icon next to the page you created that looks like a key. Click the key icon. There are a list of default rolls. Next to the "user" role click the pencil icon for "Edit Roll".
Then there's a list of users and groups that have access to the roll. At the top is an "Add +" button. Click that.
There will be a list of default groups. Click the check box next to "Anonymouse Portal User" then click the button beneath it "Ok".
This part is not intuitive because there's no save button. Just hit the link above the user roles "Page Name > User" is what it will say. Click the "Page Name" link.
Then click the "Apply" button.
Now log out and try to look at your page. It should be available for anonymous users.
-p